# What are the best tools to maintain HTML pages in multiple languages?

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

I would love to find alternatives to using MySQL + PHP. Currently thinking of using sed to replace placeholders using a dictionary per language to support during release? Any better alternative?

Comment: Did you consider using a CMS ? Most of them support i18n.

Comment: I'd prefer a lighter solution: instead of relying on heavy DB oriented solutions, I'd rather serve pure html/javascript pages, maybe adding a release phase relying on sed and language files...

Comment: I understand, since this is ultimately what CMS do, you can take the view that it's going to be quicker and more fun to do your own lightweight CMS rather than selecting one, learning it and praying for a minimal lifespan ;-)  But then you're on the right track.  Except may be for sed and placeholders, consider breaking up your pages content in templates and dive into XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logic-less templates

Mustache is a great tool for that!!

http://mustache.github.com/

Of course you should RTFM xD

http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Comment: Looks really cool but still it's not a complete solution for js/html multi-language management... unless you go full JS